# Looping Through Categories of a CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, tabs

I am trying to create tabs using the Foundations framework, outputting posts from a custom post type called **testimonial** and filtering them through their assigned custom category called **filed-under**. What am I doing wrong in my loop?

**What I Have Working**

- Category tabs appear when new categories are created

**What is Not Working**

- The posts aren't appearing in the tabbed content area
- How do you get the loop to filter the 'all' category?

**Link to Demo**
http://staging-newmummycompanyca.temp312.kinsta.cloud/testimonials/

**Code**

```
        <?php
        // TABBED HEADERS
        echo '<ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="example-tabs">';
        echo '<li class="tabs-title is-active link-no-style">';
        echo '<a href="#all" aria-selected="true">All</a>';
        echo '</li>';
        $args = array(
          'hide_empty' => 1,
          'orderby'   => 'name',
          'order'     => 'ASC',
          'post_type' => 'testimonial',
          'taxonomy'  => 'filed-under',
        );
        $categories = get_categories($args);
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
          echo
            '<li class="tabs-title link-no-style">
                <a href="#' . $category->slug . '" aria-selected="true" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">    
                  ' . $category->name . '
                </a>
              </li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';

        // TABBED CONTENT
        echo '<div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="example-tabs">';
        echo '<div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="' . $category->slug . '">';
        echo '<ul class="accordion" data-accordion data-allow-all-closed="true">';
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
          $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type'     => 'testimonial',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'category_name' => $category->slug,
          ));
          while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
            echo '<li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>';
            echo '<a href="#" class="accordion-title"><p>';
            the_title();
            echo '</p></a>';
            echo '<div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>';
            echo the_field('testimonial');
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</li>';
          endwhile;
          wp_reset_postdata();
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        ?>
```

---

**CODE V2**

```
<?php 
        echo '<ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="example-tabs">';
        echo '<li class="tabs-title is-active link-no-style">';
        echo '<a href="#" aria-selected="true">All</a>';
        echo '</li>';  

        $_terms = get_terms(array('filed-under'));
        foreach ($_terms as $term) {

        // TABBED HEADERS 
        echo '<li class="tabs-title link-no-style">';
        echo '<a href="#' . $term->slug . '"aria-selected="true" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">';
        echo $term->name;
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
        }  // CLOSE OFF FIRST LOOP 
        echo '</ul>';

        foreach ($_terms as $term) :
        $term_slug = $term->slug;
        
        // QUERY
        $_posts = new WP_Query( array(
          'post_type'         => 'testimonial',
          'posts_per_page'    => -1, 
          'tax_query' => array(
            array(
              'taxonomy' => 'filed-under',
              'field'    => 'slug',
              'terms'    => $term_slug,
            ),
          ),
        )); 
        
        // TABBED CONTENT
        echo '<div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="example-tabs">';
        echo '<div class="tabs-panel" id="' . $term_slug . '">';
        echo '<ul class="accordion" data-accordion data-allow-all-closed="true">';
        if( $_posts->have_posts() ) :  while ( $_posts->have_posts() ) : $_posts->the_post(); 
        echo '<li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>';
        echo '<a href="#" class="accordion-title">';
        echo '<p>';
        the_title(); 
        echo '</p>';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '<div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>';
        echo the_field('testimonial');
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</li>'; 
        endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        endforeach; 
        ?>
```

Comment: Can you fix the indenting on your code? It's difficult to read, there are free code editors programs that will do indenting automatically, such as Sublime Text, or Visual Studio Code

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I downloaded a plugin for Visual Code to help me in the future and have updated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
' publish',
```

This is your problem, an extra space character.

Note that in future you can catch this by using Query Monitor and by checking if posts were found. Because the post loop is missing an `if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ... } else { echo "none found"; }` type check, you had no way of knowing where to look for the problem.

Also, you're listing terms in the `filed-under` taxonomy:

```
'taxonomy'  => 'filed-under',
```

But then you're passing those terms to the `category_name` parameter, which is unrelated. So now the terms are being used as if they are terms in the category taxonomy, but they are not.

Comment: Removing the space didn't make a difference. I also added, `if ( $the_query->have_posts()) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();` and that did not work, it broke the page from rendering at all. Would you mind providing me a little more guidance? Thank you!

Comment: You need an else case and at least an `endif;` if you're going to do that. I think you should stop trying to get the tabs working and instead focusing on making sure your queries work. Doing it all at once is too much. If you can get it working as headings + bullet lists, then you can rearrange the HTML to produce the tab HTML you desire.

Comment: Also see the update I made to my answer, it looks like by using `get_categories()` and naming your variables `$categories` and `$category`, rather than using `get_terms`, `$terms` and `$term`, you've confused yourself into requesting categories when you're actually dealing with terms in the `filed-under` taxonomy, not terms in the `category` taxonomy. This is another reason your post queries aren't finding posts

Comment: Thank you. I have made some progress, but now the only thing I have left, is funneling ALL of the posts into a tab called ALL. I don't even know where to begin with doing that. Updated code is shown above.

Comment: @NatashaMcd my answer tried to solve your original question. Remember this is a Q&A site, not a discussion thread, if my answer answers your question you should mark it as accepted. If you have a new question to ask, then you should create a new question, don't move the goal post by editinng your existing question to add new requirements